# Porting Python2 file derived class to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, porting

I'm porting some Python 2 legacy code and I have this class:

```
class myfile(file):
    "Wrapper for file object whose read member returns a string buffer"
    def __init__ (self, *args):
        return file.__init__ (self, *args)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        return create_string_buffer(file.read(self, size))
```

It's used like a File object:

```
self._file = myfile(name, mode, buffering)
self._file.seek(self.si*self.blocksize)
```

I'm trying to implement it in Python 3 like so:

```
class myfile(io.FileIO):
    "Wrapper for file object whose read member returns a string buffer"
    def __init__(self, name, mode, *args, **kwargs):
        super(myfile, self).__init__(name, mode, closefd=True, *args, **kwargs)

    def read(self, size=-1):
        return create_string_buffer(self.read(size))
```

The problem is that the constructor for FileIO doesn't take the `buffering` argument and Python throws a `TypeError: fileio() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)` error.

The [Python 3 open function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is what I need. Can I inherit from that? I've looked at the [PyFile_FromFd class](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/file.html), but it needs an open file descriptor and I'm concerned that the behaviour is not going to be the same.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Are you sure that class is even needed anymore? What does ``create_string_buffer`` do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit from `open`. The buffering argument changes the class returned, so `open` is implemented as a function that can return one of several classes. Best option is to do the same thing, with your own wrapper classes if necessary.

Basic implementation idea is:

1. `myfile` is a function with a signature similar to `open`
2. You have two classes, one inheriting from `FileIO`, one from `BufferedReader`.
3. When `myfile` is invoked, it inspects the `buffering` argument, and either creates and returns the `FileIO` derived subclass (when unbuffered) or creates a normal unbuffered `FileIO` class with `open`, then wraps it in your `BufferedReader` derived subclass.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution would be monkey patching:

```
def myfile(*args, **kwargs):
    f = open(*args, **kwargs)

    def read(size=-1):
        return create_string_buffer(f._read(size))

    f._read = f.read # save old read method
    f.read = read # patch

    return f
```